# Unable to send nested array object files via multipart/form-data

Tags: node.js, nested, nestjs, multipartform-data

We have product form which is working well. But when comes with nested part then it's quite impossible to rech the files.

```js
const data = {
  name: "Working",
  // working
  images: [File, File, Files],
  variations: [
    {
      name: "Working",
      // Can't reach there and not working with multipart/form-data
      img: [File, File, File],
    },
    {
      name: "Working",
      // issue
      img: [File, File],
    },
  ],
};
```

Could you please help to figure it out How I can get the nested variations img file via multipart /form-data

Thanks

Could you please figure it out How I can reach the nested variations img in my nestjs server?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.